# List Git commits count per tag

Tags: git

Is there a way to get a nicely formated listing of tags and commits per tag?
The output I'm looking for would be something like:

```
TAG - DATE - Num of commits
------------------------------
v1.1.1 - 10/MAR/2020  -  12
v1.1.2 - 15/MAR/2020  -  15
...
```

Comment: Relative to what? The previous tag in the history of that tag?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a one shot command to do this. However :

- You can list tags starting with `v` in version order :

```
git tag --list v* --sort="v:refname"
```

- You can count the number of commits *between two points* :

```
git rev-list --count A..B

# example :
git rev-list --count v1.1.1..v1.1.2
```

- If your tags are lightweight tags placed on commits, you can get the date of the underlying commit :

```sh
# %ad for author date, %cd for committer date
$ git log -1 --format="%cd" v1.1.2

# you can tell git log to format the date using the --date option
$ git log -1 --format="%cd" v1.1.2

# you can tell git log to format the date using the --date option
$ git log -1 --date=short --format="%cd" v1.1.2
# you can use 'format:...' to specify a format for strftime() :
$ git log -1 --date="format:%Y/%b/%d" --format="%cd" v1.1.2
```

More details on the `--date` option ([full doc here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---dateltformatgt)) :

> `--date=short` shows only the date, but not the time, in YYYY-MM-DD format.
>
> [...]
>
> `--date=format:...` feeds the format `...` to your system `strftime`

---

Using these bricks, you can write a script that produces the output you want.